# Orthogonal projection on vector space of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $R_N$ be the set of $2^N$ intervals $$\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{2^N}\right), \left[\frac{1}{2^N}, \frac{2}{2^N}\right),\ldots,\left[\frac{2^N-1}{2^N}, 1\right)\right\}.$$ Let $$V_N=\operatorname{span}\{1_I\mid I\in R^N\}$$ Let $P_N:L^2([0,1])\rightarrow V_N$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V_N$.
>
> (a) Find the formula for $a_I$ such that $$P_N(f)=\sum_{I\in R_N}a_I1_I$$ for $f\in L^2([0,1])$.
>
> (b) Suppose $f\in C([0,1])$. Show that $P_N(f)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$ to $f$.

For part (a) I think we should have $a_I=2^N\langle f,1_I\rangle$. Then we will have $P_N(1_I)=2^N\langle 1_I,1_I\rangle 1_I=1_I$ , so $P_N(f)=f$ for all $f\in V_N$. Now let $f\in L^2([0,1])$. How can I show that $P_N(f)\perp (f-P_N(f))$?

Also, what should I use for part (b) to show uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your answer to (a) appears to be correct.
2. To check $P_N(f)\perp f-P_N(f)$, just compute their inner product. You will end up with something that looks like
   $$
   \sum a_I\langle 1_I, f\rangle - \sum |a_I|^2\langle 1_I, 1_I\rangle
   $$
   now use the fact that $a_I = 2^n\langle f,1_I\rangle$ to get this to be zero.
3. For any $f\in C[0,1]$, and $\epsilon > 0$, by uniform continuity of $f$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
   $$
   x \in I_j := \left [ \frac{j-1}{2^N}, \frac{j}{2^N} \right ] \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(j/2^N)|<\epsilon/2
   $$
   Now
   $$
   |a_{I_j} - f(j/2^N)| = \left |2^N \int_{I_j} f(x)dx - 2^N \int_{I_j}f(j/2^N)dx \right | 
   $$
   $$
   \leq 2^N \int_{I_j} |f(x) - f(j/2^N)|dx < \epsilon/2
   $$
   Hence,
   $$
   \|P_N(f) - f\| \leq \|\sum a_{I_j} 1_{I_j} - \sum f(j/2^N)1_{I_j}\| + \|\sum f(j/2^n)1_{I_j} - f\|
   $$
   and each term is $<\epsilon/2$

Comment: Thanks Prahlad... but I don't see why $|a_{I_j}-f(j/2^N)|<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: @MikaH. : I have added a line by way of explanation.